# How Can I get the clicked or active number of tab?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

**HTML**

```html
<div class="tabbable tabs-left">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li><a href="#menu23" data-toggle="tab">Beethoven</a></li>
        <li><a href="#menu24" data-toggle="tab">Bach</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane" id="menu23">
            item1
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="menu24">
            item2
        </div>
    </div>
```

I want to get the tab index number not tab name.

Such as:

- if `Beethoven` is clicked, I need `0`;
- if `Bach` is clicked, I need `1`;

I made this code from this [document](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/)

```js
$('#myTab a').click(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
     // How do I get tab number....??
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```js
$('.nav-tabs a').click(function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     alert($($(this).attr('href')).index());
});
```

Or with bootstrap's events

```js
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown', function (e) {
  $(e.target).index();
})
```

Comment: you need to use: $(document).on('shown.bs.tab', ....) - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23211543/tab-shown-event-not-firing-twitter-bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it without a click event you can use this:

```
var tabIdx = $('.dashboardTab.active').data("tabidx");
console.log(tabIdx);
```

Answer (score -1):

We have direct API for this.

```
currentIndex
```

Returns the zero based index number for the current tab.
for more- https://github.com/VinceG/twitter-bootstrap-wizard

Comment: this answer is in no way helpful