# Tab "shown" event not firing - Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

When a tab changes, I'm attempting to fire an ajax call. However, I can't even seem to get this basic test to work:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
   <li class="">
      <a data-toggle="tab" href="#gqs-uploader" id="gqs-uploader-btn">Upload</a>
   </li>
   <li class="active">
      <a data-toggle="tab" href="#gqs-results" id="gqs-results-btn">Results</a>
   </li>
   <li class="">
      <a data-toggle="tab" href="#gqs-download" id="gqs-download-btn">Download</a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

And the javascript:

```
(function ( $ ) {
    "use strict";

    $(function () {
        $(document).on('shown', 'a[data-toggle="tab"]', function (e) {
            alert('TAB CHANGED');
        });
    }); 

}(jQuery));
```

When ANY tab changes, it should send me an alert.

**Why is this simple example not working?**

The basic example in the docs does not work either. The entire event (even button clicks) seems invisible - I can't seem to catch it any way.

Comment: What is your bootstrap version?

Comment: The bootstrap docs for the current version 3.1.1 mention that the tab shown event name is `shown.bs.tab`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try this

```
$(document).on('shown.bs.tab', 'a[data-toggle="tab"]', function (e) {
    alert('TAB CHANGED');
})
```

Comment: This was it, - a silly oversight on my part - reading docs for wrong version.

Comment: Interestingly, [the solution for this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20705905/bootstrap-3-jquery-event-for-active-tab-change), which is the first result for google keywords "tab change event bootstrap" did not fire the event for my AngularJS code. However, this solution successfully fired the event.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code, check working [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/subodhghulaxe/8xYRs/)

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
   <li class="">
      <a data-toggle="tab" href="#gqs-uploader" id="gqs-uploader-btn">Upload</a>
   </li>
   <li class="active">
      <a data-toggle="tab" href="#gqs-results" id="gqs-results-btn">Results</a>
   </li>
   <li class="">
      <a data-toggle="tab" href="#gqs-download" id="gqs-download-btn">Download</a>
   </li>
</ul>

<script>
    (function ( $ ) {
        $(function () {
            $(document).on('shown.bs.tab', 'a[data-toggle="tab"]', function (e) {
                alert('TAB CHANGED');
            });
        }); 
    }(jQuery));
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is from the bootstrap documentation:
http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
  e.target // newly activated tab
  e.relatedTarget // previous active tab
})
```

You have 4 events:
hide, show, hidden, shown